Flutter project Running issue
i am new to the app development when i was running my first project in my vs code editor i am facing the below issues anyone please guide me to resolve this issues
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. * Where: Build file 'C:\Users\mikeD\\Documents\Android_project\firstone\android\build.gradle' line: 26 * What went wrong: A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'. > A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not open proj generic class cache for build file 'C:\mikeD\Users\D\Documents\Android_project\firstone\android\app\build.gradle' (C:\Users\mikeD\.gradle\caches\7.5\scripts\6rff7y4jfvqem1y74rqxlyw1r).
      > BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '_BuildScript_' Unsupported class file major version 66

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.



restart your device
run flutter doctor
then open your project and select the device.
run the project running without debugging
if still there error try to run on the web if it is working delete the emulator and create it again and this will work

